# Why does delete method not updated the list?

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, vuex

Working Todo application using VueJS, Vuex and MongoDB, after delete a task my list does not updated without refresh page. I already add a dispatch `GET_TASK` in promise awaiting the list update, but it is not working, and seems which this promise even not execute.

```
<template>
    <div class="flex-col mx-auto mt-10 min-w-max font-sans text-xl" style="width:512px">
        <ul class="space-y-2">
            <li class="flex justify-between px-4 min-h-full" v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
                {{task.task}} 
                <button @click="deletetodo(task._id)" class="text-xs border-2 px-4 focus:outline-none hover:bg-blue-200 hover:text-white rounded-full">Delete</button>    
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"ListToDo",
    computed:{
        tasks: function(){
            return this.$store.state.task
        }
    },
    methods:{
        async getlisttodo(){
            await this.$store.dispatch("GET_TASK")
        },
        async deletetodo(id){
            await this.$store.dispatch("DELETE_TASK",{'id':id})
            .then(response => {
                this.$store.dispatch("GET_TASK")
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(`DeleteTodo ${error}`))
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getlisttodo()
    }
}
</script>
```

Vuex:

```
   actions: {
        async GET_TASK({ commit }) {
            const rawResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/tasks')
            const content = await rawResponse.json();
            commit("SET_TASK", content)
        },

        async SAVE_TASK({ commit }, object) {
            const rawResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/save', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 'task': object })
            });
            const content = await rawResponse.json();
            commit("SET_MESSAGE", content)
        },

        async DELETE_TASK({ commit }, obj) {
            const id = obj['id']
            const raw = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/delete/${id}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 'id': id })
            });
            const content = await raw.json();
            commit("SET_MESSAGE", content)
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you just do a `splice` in your mutation

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you can use `array splice` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice to remove an array in your Vuex Mutations. So you need to create new mutations e.g. "DELETE_MESSAGE"

Comment: also I guess you need to remove that `await` from `raw.json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to fix that by adding `DELETE METHOD`

vuex:

```
async DELETE_TASK({ commit }, obj) {
    try {
        const id = obj['id']
        const raw = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/delete/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 'id': id })
        });
        const content = await raw.json();
        commit("SET_MESSAGE", content)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`DELETE_TASK ${error}`)
    }
}
```

server.js

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.body.id;
        TodoTask.findByIdAndDelete(id, err => {
            if (err) return res.send(500, err);
            res.send({ 'status': 200, "mensagem": 'Tarefa deletada' })
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error Delete ${error}`)
    }
})
```

ListTodo.vue

```
methods:{        
    async deletetodo(id){
        try{
            await this.$store.dispatch("DELETE_TASK",{'id':id})
            .then(response => {
                this.$store.dispatch("GET_TASK");
                console.log(response);
            }) 
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }catch(error){
            console.log(`DeleteTodo ${error}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just skimming through it seems that you are awaiting an async method and also doing .then.
If you are awaiting a method, then the task will wait until it fullfills the promise before going to the next line.
([more info on async/await here](https://javascript.info/async-await))

Also I'm not sure if response is being returned when you are dispatching "DELETE_TASK". I see a "SET_MESSAGE" being called within that method. You can always check my console.logging.
if that's the case try changing delete todo method as follows

```js
async deletetodo(id){
           
           try{
           let response = await this.$store.dispatch("DELETE_TASK",{'id':id});
           this.$store.dispatch("GET_TASK");
                console.log(response);
            }
            catch(error){
            console.log(`DeleteTodo ${error}`)
            }
        }
```

Happy Coding!